# Is there a generalized definition of symmetry which results in a symmetry quasigroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetry, quasigroups

I've been looking at generalized definitions of symmetry.  Symmetries, the way we usually define them, form a group.  However, there have been efforts to generalize this, creating algebras which have weaker properties.  I have heard of a non-invertable concept of symmetry which yields a symmetry semigroup.  I have also heard of one which leads to a symmetry groupoid.

Has there been any significant attempt to define a generalized concept of symmetry whose algebra is a quasigroup or a loop?  I have been biased by [answers like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94951/153899) and my own love of the associative property, so I have been having trouble breaking free of those assumptions.

Comment: Note that such "nonassociative symmetries" would have to depart from the usual picture in one of two ways: either the way they combine isn't via composition or they're not actually functions, since function composition is always associative.

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended to be a proper 'answer', but it's far too long to fit in a comment. It's an attempt to elaborate both on the question by Cort Ammon and on the comment by Noah Schweber.

Imagine we have a semigroup (it's easy to adapt this reasoning for a monoid or a group if one wishes) whose composition law *changes with time*. More precisely, we start with a set $G$ equipped with a function

$${\cal T}\times G\times G\rightarrow G,\qquad(t,g,g')\mapsto g'\circ_t g.$$

It seems natural to require the composition to behave as usually with respect to a fixed instant of time. This means: for each $t\in\cal T$ and $g,g',g''\in G$, the *static* composition shall be associative:

$$g''\circ_t(g'\circ_t g)=(g''\circ_t g')\circ_t g.$$

However, with respect to different instants of time, the *temporal* composition doesn't have necessarily to be associative anymore. This means: for some $t_1,t_2\in\cal T$ and $g,g',g''\in G$, we may have

$$g''\circ_{t_2}(g'\circ_{t_1} g)\ne(g''\circ_{t_2} g')\circ_{t_1} g.$$

Of course, this construction looks somewhat artificial, and indeed I've never heard of anything like that before. But, doesn't it throw some light on a possible hidden relationship between *associativity* and *permanence in time*?

Now, if someone wanted to try and think about this 'notion' as the 'symmetry group' of some concrete object, maybe a [tensegrity structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensegrity) could be a nice starting point. For instance, one such structure that happened to admit multiple solutions, possibly related by some abrupt deformations, would probably have a very interesting 'symmetry group' to think about.

Comment: Another way to think about this 'trip' might be as if each 'composition step' had a 'cost' in time, or something of that type...

Comment: That is a very helpful not-an-answer indeed.  It is most definitely along the lines of the strings I'm trying to tug on.  Your reference to tensegrity is particularly intriguing because this line of mathematical thinking I've been working through started with physics based disciplines which have a strong predilection towards tensegrity structures.